# increment in while loop doesn't work?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am doing the following while loop, and the line number doesn't get incremented (it's always 0). Why is that?

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
    int line_number = 0;
    int f = 0;
    while (f == 0) {
        printf("LINE NUMBER IS %f\n", line_number);
        line_number++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(I realize this is an infinite loop, but I am interested here in why line_number isn't getting incremented.)

Comment: Types are everything...

Comment: ,,as are format specifiers.

Comment: As are compiler warnings

Comment: It gets incremented just fine.

Comment: `const char* argv[]` -> undefined behaviour. `*argv[]` shall not be `const` qualified. `Plus other errors. Almost as many as lines.

Comment: Many warnings, you ignore! Please don't do that! In the future, ask a question about *the warnings* which, in this case (this being *the usual case*), caused *the problem*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `printf`, it matters what letter you put after a `%` sign for variable replacement. If you look at [the list of format specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), you’ll see that `%f` is for floating-point numbers. This means it thinks `line_number` is a float; it doesn’t do the proper conversion because it doesn’t realize it needs to, and instead just reads the same bits as a float.

The way the floating-point format works is [complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), but you’ll stay very close to zero for a very long time. Depending on how fast your computer is and how patient you are, you might or might not see it change if you leave it running for longer.

(Technically it’s even worse than this, as this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); however, this is the most likely outcome.)

---

Most compilers will have some option to warn you if you use the wrong format specifier; you should probably turn on the default set of compiler warnings so it can tell you about this and other issues.